# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\

Tags: php, calendar, jscript

```
$stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT name, date, start FROM bookings WHERE date LIKE  CONCAT(?, '-', ?, '%')"); //Sql query for name ,date ,start time
$this->is_slot_booked_today = 0; 
// Defaults to 0
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$year,$month);   

//this is where error is pointing line 72
$stmt->bind_result($name, $date, $start);
```

There is more code but i want to highlight this particular for error what I am getting here. I am creating time slot booking calendar.

Comment: Sounds like the `prepare` failed. Check for errors there, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: So what should i do now change the statement of sql or something else?

Comment: You'll probably have to use both. Use the error function to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More than likely `prepare()` failed and `$stmt` is `false`, instead on a `PDOStatement` object

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

From http://php.net/manual/ro/pdo.prepare.php

UPDATE:

Same thing for mysqli:
`mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.`
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: This is `mysqli`, not `PDO` (or OP is using the wrong driver functions).

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is some html field data is not inserting in database of MySQL, code is

```
$insert_query="
  insert into employee_create
  (emp_id,first_name,last_name,date_of_birth,gender,address,nationality,
   date_of_joining,pan_detail,contact_number,altcontact_number,role,
   manager_id) values('$empid','$fname','$lname','$dob','$gender','$address','$nationality','$doj','$pan','$contact','$acontact','$role','$manager')
";
```